¿Como se desinstala un paquete nodejs o programa instalado con curl en linux debian?
intente instalar un plugin para Vim que me exigía tener instalado Nodejs pero al instalarlo no era lo que me esperaba. Desinstale el plugin pero el problema es que no se como desinstalar el Nodejs que instale con curl
curl -sL install-node.vercel.app/lts | bash

Específicamente quiero desinstalar este programa pero no ayo como hacerlo aunque también me gustaría saber adicionalmente como en general desinstalar los paquetes instalados con curl. Gracias y disculpen la molestia.

curl solo baja archivos; no los instala ni los ejecuta. Es bash (en tu ejemplo) quien ejecuta el script que bajastes. El script es cualquier cosa, no necesariamente un instalador. El mecanismo de desintalación debe ser proporcionado por el autor del script y no hay un procedimiento estándar. Puede ser desintalado borrando los archivos generados o bien corriendo un ejecutable instalado por el mismo script (entre otras alternativas). En resumen, depende.

@CandidMoe, ya alguien tuvo el mismo problema

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-from-windows/

El comando lo único que hace es usar curl para descargar un script (https://github.com/vercel/install-node/blob/master/install.sh) y usa bash para ejecutarlo. Ese script en esencia detecta el sistema operativo y la arquitectura y descarga la version de Node especificada de https://nodejs.org. Simplmente descarga el  tarball y lo descomprime en el directorio adecuado, como /usr.  El script no proporciona una opción para automatizar la desinstalación, tendrás que hacerlo manualmente como si lo hubieras instalado Node manualmente desde las fuentes.

Para desinstalarlo deberás eliminar los binarios copiados (posiblemente en /usr/bin/node, ejecutando which node puedes obtener el directorio de instalación en tu caso), directorios auxiliares (/usr/local/lib/node_modules, /usr/local/include/node, etc), cualquier archivo de configuración...  No es algo universal, mirate algunos tutoriales sobre ello buscando algo como "how to completely uninstall node in linux", ignora cualquier instrucción acerca de eliminar paquetes de apt , dnf, pacman..., ya que tu no has instalado desde el gestor de paquetes de tu distro.

@dsad ¿Y el resto de los archivos como los borra?

No hay un método estándar, depende del script y de ti.

Eliminar binarios específicos de Node.js: Localiza y elimina solo los binarios de Node.js ejecutando which node y which npm y eliminando esos archivos.

Eliminar directorios específicos de la instalación: Verifica si el script creó un sub-directorio específico para Node.js (usualmente en /usr/local/ o /opt/) y elimina solo ese directorio.

Evitar afectar otros programas: No borres carpetas globales como /usr/local/lib/node_modules o /usr/local/include/node si otros programas dependen de ellas.


De esta manera, reduces el riesgo de afectar otros programas.
